# How to select dropdown option by matching text?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I want to select dropdown option by matching option text.

HTML code:

```
<li title="Add Page" class="dropdown-header ng-scope" data-ng-if="selectedPage">Add Page</li> 
<li title="Add page before the current page" data-ng-if="selectedPage" class="ng-scope">
<a data-ng-click="addPage(selectedPage, 'before')">Before Selected</a>   </li>
<li title="Add page after the current page" data-ng-if="selectedPage" class="ng-scope">
<a data-ng-click="addPage(selectedPage, 'after')">After Selected</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `by.xpath()` and check the `a` element's text:

```
element(by.xpath('//li/a[. = "Before Selected"]')).click();
```

Or, by link text:

```
element(by.linkText("Before Selected")).click();
```

Comment: Alex I don't want to use xapth. Is there any other way?

Comment: I prefer the `by.linkText` method of this answer, it just looks cleaner. Does it have any downside compared to `by.xpath`?

Comment: @Aaron I usually use `by.linkText` whenever it feels logical cause it makes the test cleaner and more explicit comparing to having an xpath expression. Thanks.

Comment: @RashmiChauhan has the answer helped to solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used:

```
.click().sendKeys();
```

to select options from my drop downs. Haven't had a problem yet.